# Obtaining more detailed error information from a callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging, webforms, callback

My callback is returning the following message: 'Invalid response from server.'

Here is my function that tells me there is an invalid response from the server:

```
function sampleCallBack_Error(sender, eventArgs) {
alert("ERROR LOADING INFORMATION" + eventArgs.get_message());
}
```

What other information can I retrieve besides just get_message?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the entire eventArgs object, it should contain more useful information.

```
function sampleCallBack_Error(sender, eventArgs) {
    console.log(eventArgs);
}
```

Comment: I end up getting [Object object] with functions() and __proto__ I tried drilling down and I am finding nothing.